# Round in excel last digit is 0 or 5

Tags: excel, vba, function, rounding, calculation

I would like to round a return value in excel with request below, it always > 0:
If number is < 3 so round to 4 digits(ex: 0.0347)
If number is < 15 so round to 3 digits but last digit is only 0 or 5( ex: 3.745, 6.340...)
if number is < 60 so round 2 digits( ex: 25.43...)
How to do that with function in excel?

Comment: Something like: `=IF(A1<3,ROUND(A1,4),IF(AND(A1>=3,A1<15),ROUND(A1,3),IF(AND(A1>=15,A1<60),ROUND(A1,2),A1)))` Not sure what you mean about the last digit only a 0 or 5? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @Simon change the `ROUND(A1,3)` to `MROUND(A1,0.005)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah didn't even know about that one. Useful!